# Is it possible to write an exclusive case among certain types with typescript switch case?

Tags: typescript, switch-statement

Is it possible to construct a switch case statement so that one of the cases is type of "any from accepted values except this and that"?

My problem is that I have a huge switch case statement, where two cases are sort of exceptions and then rest are more or less similar which could be extracted into their own handler.

```
switch (values) {
  case "abc":
    return something
  case "def":
    return something
  case (everything else from values except "abc" and "def"):
    return something
  default:
    return defaultStuff
```

One extra twist into the problem is that the types of these values comes from larger type"hell" in the project I am working on. They are some sort of literals if that's any help. But I don't think it is smart to go deep into that and try to alter the types in anyway.

Is this kind of exclusion possible?

Comment: You can pre-process the values so a switch/case is possible. Else, why not use if-elseif-else? This is not a typical switch/case scenario

Comment: Looks like `everything else from values except "abc" and "def"` is equal to `default` case.

Comment: I think the previously chosen switch-case instead of if-else was an attempt to make the code cleaner. Now that I am refactoring and extracting parts of it to elsewhere, if-else structure could be a reasonable choice @lean